# How to include 0 in the result of count query

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, count, aggregate-functions

I have 4 tables that stores 4 kind of request: Time-off (TO), Meeting (MT), PO and Travel (TR).

I want to count total requests of each type in each table in the last 30 days:

```
  SELECT [requestType], COUNT ([requestType]) As 'Count' 
  FROM [Timeoff] 
  WHERE [requestType] = 'TO' AND CAST([timeoffCreatedTime] AS DATE) >= CAST(DateAdd(DAY,-30,Getdate()) AS DATE) GROUP BY [requestType]
  UNION ALL
  SELECT [requestType], COUNT ([requestType]) As 'Count' 
  FROM [Meeting] 
  WHERE [requestType] = 'MT' AND CAST([meetingCreatedTime] AS DATE) >= CAST(DateAdd(DAY,-30,Getdate()) AS DATE) GROUP BY [requestType]
  UNION ALL
  SELECT [requestType], COUNT ([requestType]) As 'Count' 
  FROM [PO] 
  WHERE [requestType] = 'PO' AND CAST([poCreatedTime] AS DATE) >= CAST(DateAdd(DAY,-30,Getdate()) AS DATE) GROUP BY [requestType]
  UNION ALL
  SELECT [requestType], COUNT ([requestType]) As 'Count' 
  FROM [Travel] 
  WHERE [requestType] = 'TR' AND CAST([travelCreatedTime] AS DATE) >= CAST(DateAdd(DAY,-30,Getdate()) AS DATE) GROUP BY [requestType]
```

Problem is that, if the count is 0 then it won't show up at all in the result, for example if Meeting requests's count = 0 then I only have this as result:

[image]

How do I include the 0 value in the result, so I will have something like that (if Meeting MT count = 0):

> requestType   --- Count
>
> TO    ------------- 30
>
> MT  ------------- 0
>
> PO    -------------19
>
> TR    -------------9

Comment: why do you write the Group By clause?
I think it is not needed as my written solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to remove the GROUP BY from your queries, it is not needed!
your query should simply be :

```
SELECT 'TO' AS [requestType], COUNT ([requestType]) As 'Count' 
  FROM [Timeoff] 
  WHERE [requestType] = 'TO' AND CAST([timeoffCreaime] ATE) >= CASt(DAY,-30,Gte()) ATE)
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Meeting' AS [requestType], COUNT ([requestType]) As 'Count' 
  FROM [Meeting] 
  WHERE [requestType] = 'Meeting' AND CAST([meetingCreaime] ATE) >= CASt(DAY,-30,Gte()) ATE)
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 'PO' AS [requestType], COUNT ([requestType]) As 'Count' 
  FROM [PO] 
  WHERE [requestType] = 'PO' AND CAST([poCreaime] ATE) >= CASt(DAY,-30,Gte()) ATE)
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 'TR' AS [requestType], COUNT ([requestType]) As 'Count' 
  FROM [Travel] 
  WHERE [requestType] = 'TR' AND CAST([travelCreaime] ATE) >= CASt(DAY,-30,Gte()) ATE)
```

Comment: It is already hardcoded this way, he needs it in the the WHERE filters as I don't know his business logic.

Comment: I rolled back the edit to take it back to its original state. To make your code work you need to remove `RequestType` from select statement and hardcode the `RequestType`.

Comment: @AnupAgrawal why do you edit my solution that contains the horcoding of requestType ... then asking to do so ? :)
The Ronaldinho code works fine and just needs removing the GROUP BY clause to get also the 0 counts in the results. I think it should be then a correct answer. thank you

Comment: Here you can see the revision history. http://stackoverflow.com/posts/35074523/revisions . Your code didn't had the hardcoding and on your request I rolled back my edit which had the hardcode.

Comment: @AnupAgrawal I got now what do you mean, I made the hardcoding back :)
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can either do an outer join on each query to something like (select 1)

```
SELECT [requestType], COUNT ([requestType]) As 'Count' 
  FROM (select 1 as foo) bar
  LEFT JOIN [CTEite].[dbo].[Timeoff] ON 1=1
  WHERE [requestType] = 'TO' AND CAST([timeoffCreaime] ATE) >= CASt(DAY,-
```

or UNION and sum

```
WITH foo AS(
SELECT 'TO' as [requestType], 0 as [Count]
UNION ALL
SELECT 'MT', 0
UNION ALL
....
)
SELECT [requestType], sum([Count])
FROM
(SELECT [requestType], COUNT ([requestType]) As 'Count' 
  FROM [CTEite].[dbo].[Timeoff] 
  WHERE [requestType] = 'TO' AND CAST([timeoffCreaime] ATE) >= CASt(DAY,-30,Gte()) ATE) GROUP BY [requestType]
  UNION ALL
  SELECT [requestType], COUNT ([requestType]) As 'Count' 
  FROM [CTEite].[dbo].[Meeting] 
  WHERE [requestType] = 'Meeting' AND CAST([meetingCreaime] ATE) >= CASt(DAY,-30,Gte()) ATE) GROUP BY [requestType]
  UNION ALL
  SELECT [requestType], COUNT ([requestType]) As 'Count' 
  FROM [CTEite].[dbo].[PO] 
  WHERE [requestType] = 'PO' AND CAST([poCreaime] ATE) >= CASt(DAY,-30,Gte()) ATE) GROUP BY [requestType]
  UNION ALL
  SELECT [requestType], COUNT ([requestType]) As 'Count' 
  FROM [CTEite].[dbo].[Travel] 
  WHERE [requestType] = 'TR' AND CAST([travelCreaime] ATE) >= CASt(DAY,-30,Gte()) ATE) GROUP BY [requestType]
 UNION SELECT * FROM foo)
GROUP BY [requestType]
```